# MATE 1.8.0: how to set Ctrl+Escape shortcut for main menu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint, mate

I used to use Linux Mint 13 MATE for some time, it has MATE 1.2.0, in which I can set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut for opening main menu by right-click on the `Menu button -> Preferences`, there is a simple text field in which I can manually enter the following text: `<Control>Escape`, and it works. (logoff + logon is needed to apply changes, though)

Now I tried Linux Mint 17, it has MATE 1.8.0, and there is no text field anymore: now, there is automatic shortcut picker. The thing is that it fails to grab the same shortcut: just when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> it doesn't care that I actually hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key already, assumes I canceled entering, and just returns previous value.

It's interesting that in general keybinding settings (`mate-keybinding-properties`) shortcut picker is more smart: it easily allows to enter shortcut with <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. But, in the `mate-keybinding-properties`, it's impossible to set shortcut for opening main menu. (iteresting why it is separated, btw)

So, how to achieve what I need: how to set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> shortcut for opening main menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experiments, got it: first of all, we need for `dconf-editor`:

```
$ sudo aptitude install dconf-tools
$ dconf-editor
```

Go to `com` → `linuxmint` → `mintmenu`, find `hot-key` property, and set the following text there:

```
<Primary>Escape
```

Note it's case-sensitive. After that, the hotkey should work immediately (even without closing `dconf-editor`, or anything)